# Use the intersection of the following sets to prove the integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

if $0 \in \{ f(0),g(0)\} \cap \{f(e),g(e)\}$ prove that$\int_0^e f(x)g'(x)= -\int_0^e g(x)f'(x)$. 
 I am lost on this one this looks very similar the theory of integration by parts

Comment: I don't understand your first expression.  You seem to have $\{( \dots )\}$ where these parentheses are a matched pair...

Comment: I have tried to “fix” the first condition, please check if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=f(e)g(e)-f(0)g(0)$$
$$=\int_0^e \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))dx$$
$$=\int_0^e(f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x))dx$$
$$=\int_0^e f(x)g'(x)dx+\int_0^e f'(x)g(x)dx$$
which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

That *is* integration by parts: $0 \in \{ f(0),g(0)\}$ and $0 \in \{f(e),g(e)\}$, so that one of $f(0)$, $g(0)$ and one of $f(e)$, $g(e)$ is zero. Therefore 
$$
\int_0^e f(x)g'(x)= f(e)g(e) - f(0)g(0) -\int_0^e g(x)f'(x) = -\int_0^e g(x)f'(x) \, .
$$